# Error on add Action Bar Sherlock and AppCompat v7 in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-styles

I'm trying to use Action Bar Sherlock, but the libraries give an error on Add, I made a screenshot to explain this situation better:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppCompat and ActionBarSherlock define the same resources because they're designed to do the same thing! You only need to use one or the other.

Comment: Thanks, i solve removing the appcompat v7 and removing namespaces of my activity, when i create my project i add whit actionBar because this has the second conflict. Thanks man.